# How to merge extractor fan ducting

Tags: ducts, ventilation, uk

I have an kitchen extractor hood that vents air through a 5-inch flexible ducting to a louvred cover in the outside wall.

I'd like to add a similar piece of ducting to vent the tumble dryer outside, plus I'd like to add another length to add an extractor fan to vent the bathroom

The layout of the flat makes it quite easy to bring all three lengths of ducting to the inside of the property next to the existing hole.

Normally I'd just cut a couple of extra holes in the wall and have one duct per hole. However, my lease-hold agreement prevents me making *any* change to the exterior of the building. Also, the wall is quite high so cutting some new holes would require the expense of scaffolding and/or a cherry picker.

So, is it possible to merge three sets of 5 inch ducting, *without* the danger of one duct back-venting to another (*for example, the bathroom venting back through the kitchen extractor hood*).

I know I can get back-draft shutters for a single length but what I really need is a junction box with three entrances and one exit, is this allowed?

Comment: Have you asked permission to add a drier and bathroom fan? If so, then have you asked if the landlord would pay for or help pay for the needed venting?  You can not combine the three into one. You need three separate ducts and vents. Where in the world are you and are there codes in place for your area?